# FFMPEG RGB Lossless conversion video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been experiencing difficulty in finding many answers with FFMPEG documentation, forums and here.
What I am trying to do is a compress a screen capture video but with just RGB data.
The steps I am currently taking are;

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -pix_fmt 0rgb -r "30" -i "1" -vcodec libx264rgb -pix_fmt rgb24 -crf 0 -t 25 -q 0 -y ~/Desktop/RGB.mkv 

south-58-45:~ danielcarter$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -pix_fmt 0rgb -r "30" -i "1" -vcodec libx264rgb -pix_fmt rgb24 -crf 0 -t 170 -q 0 -y -v info ~/Desktop/output.mkv
ffmpeg version 3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[avfoundation @ 0x7fc39d004c00] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, avfoundation, from '1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 175270.249500, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo ([0]RGB / 0x42475200), 0rgb, 1440x900, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264rgb))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] 264 - core 148 r2748 97eaef2 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=0 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=0 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=cqp mbtree=0 qp=0
Output #0, matroska, to '/Users/danielcarter/Desktop/output.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264rgb) (H264 / 0x34363248), rgb24, 1440x900, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264rgb
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame= 5100 fps= 30 q=-1.0 Lsize=   12167kB time=00:02:49.96 bitrate= 586.4kbits/s speed=0.999x    
video:12134kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.267659%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] frame I:21    Avg QP: 0.00  size:430796
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] frame P:5079  Avg QP: 0.00  size:   665
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] mb I  I16..4: 61.3%  0.0% 38.7%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.9%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] 8x8 transform intra:0.0% inter:11.2%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] coded y,u,v intra: 48.0% 31.6% 29.0% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 76% 22%  2%  0%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 46% 35%  7%  2%  2%  1%  1%  1%  3%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] ref P L0: 83.1%  6.4%  5.3%  5.2%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fc39d13ea00] kb/s:584.71
```

This captures the screen on my mac. To the best of my knowledge, this creates a lossless file and I have compared screen shots that confirm this.
The next step is where I think I have an issue.
Because I want to run the compression on raw RGB data I need to convert the MKV to an RGB file;

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/RGB.mkv -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -crf 0 -ss 00:00:03 -to 00:02:01 -q 0 -y ~/Desktop/out.rgb

south-58-45:~ danielcarter$ ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/output.mkv -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -crf 0 -ss 00:00:03 -to 00:02:01 -q 0 -y ~/Desktop/out.rgb
ffmpeg version 3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/Users/danielcarter/Desktop/output.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:02:50.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 586 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive), gbrp(tv, gbr/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1440x900, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264rgb
      DURATION        : 00:02:50.000000000
Codec AVOption crf (Select the quality for constant quality mode) specified for output file #0 (/Users/danielcarter/Desktop/out.rgb) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, rawvideo, to '/Users/danielcarter/Desktop/out.rgb':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 1440x900, q=2-31, 933120 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:02:50.000000000
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 rawvideo
frame= 3540 fps=111 q=-0.0 Lsize=13440938kB time=00:01:58.00 bitrate=933120.0kbits/s speed=3.68x    
video:13440938kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
```

Once I have this I can then compress and decompress successfully. I then get a working file to play back using;

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1440x900 -r 30 -pix_fmt rgb24 -i ~/Desktop/out.rgb -c:v libx264rgb -pix_fmt rgb24 -x264opts keyint=300:min-keyint=300:no-scenecut -y -crf 0 ~/Desktop/rgbplay.mkv

south-58-45:~ danielcarter$ ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1440x900 -r 30 -pix_fmt rgb24 -i ~/Desktop/out.rgb -c:v libx264rgb -pix_fmt rgb24 -x264opts keyint=300:min-keyint=300:no-scenecut -y -crf 0 ~/Desktop/rgbplay.mkv
ffmpeg version 3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[rawvideo @ 0x7fb1f9002600] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from '/Users/danielcarter/Desktop/out.rgb':
  Duration: 00:01:58.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 933120 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 1440x900, 933120 kb/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264rgb))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] 264 - core 148 r2748 97eaef2 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=0 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=0 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=2 keyint=300 keyint_min=151 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=cqp mbtree=0 qp=0
Output #0, matroska, to '/Users/danielcarter/Desktop/rgbplay.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264rgb) (H264 / 0x34363248), rgb24, 1440x900, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264rgb
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame= 3540 fps= 64 q=-1.0 Lsize=    8319kB time=00:01:57.96 bitrate= 577.7kbits/s speed=2.13x    
video:8297kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.273154%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] frame I:12    Avg QP: 0.00  size:437670
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] frame P:3528  Avg QP: 0.00  size:   919
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] mb I  I16..4: 61.9%  0.0% 38.1%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.8%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] 8x8 transform intra:0.0% inter:15.1%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] coded y,u,v intra: 49.7% 36.5% 33.7% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 73% 25%  1%  0%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 45% 36%  7%  2%  2%  2%  2%  1%  3%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] ref P L0: 81.3%  7.7%  6.7%  4.3%
[libx264rgb @ 0x7fb1f9010c00] kb/s:575.96
```

But here I have pixel variance. My guess is there is a RGB-YUV-RGB conversion happening somewhere but I am not smart enough to work out where.
If any of you can help I would forever grateful.

Here is a picture of the two stills side by side that shows the differences;

[pixel difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYKby.png)

If you need anything more I can post it also.
Cheers,
DC

Comment: Could you provide the full, uncut output of the ffmpeg executable when running each of the above commandlines with -v info? In particular, it'd be interesting to see the setup of swscale (if any).

Comment: Added the output

Comment: Your MKV is marked as having range TV. RGB formats should be pc/full.

Comment: @Mulvya how do I set that? I found out_range is there but came up as an unrecognised option

Comment: It is not a problem that it is marked as limited (though for gdigrub it was recently fixed) because limited range RGB is not supported by ffmpeg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by removing a step.
The conversion from mkv->rgb was producing the problem, it was using gbrp as the pixel format and this created slight differences in colour across the whole screen. Thank you to Mulvya for pointing out the range markers too, without that I would not have known where to look.

To get this to work I use the following code to screen capture direct to RGB;

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -pix_fmt 0rgb -color_range 2 -r "30" -i "1" -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -color_range 2 -t 210 -q 0 -y -v info ~/Desktop/output.rgb
```

Then can convert that to an MKV file for playback using;

```
ffmpeg -report -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1440x900 -r 30 -pix_fmt rgb24 -color_range 2 -i ~/Desktop/output.rgb -c:v libx264rgb -pix_fmt rgb24 -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:02:02 -color_range 2 -x264opts crf=0 -y  ~/Desktop/rgbplay.mkv
```

Thank you for everything, I can sleep again haha